# innodb_additional_mem_pool_size in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

Official MySQL documentation says:

> innodb_use_sys_malloc and innodb_additional_mem_pool_size were
>   deprecated in MySQL 5.6 and removed in MySQL 5.7.

Is there an alternative to this parameter in MySQL 5.7?
How i can specify additional memory size for MySQL with manual mode?

Answer (score 3):

"Deprecated" means that it is no longer used/supported/coded/etc.  The only reason it was not immediately removed (eg, in MySQL 5.6.3) was to give users some warning rather than immediately invalidating `my.cnf` files all over the world.

There is no need for those settings; remove them from your configuration.

BTW, more things will be removed in MySQL 8.0 -- for example all of the Query Cache settings.

The Changelog for 5.6.3 says

> The following items are deprecated and will be removed in a future MySQL release. Where alternatives are shown, applications should be updated to use them.
>
> The innodb_table_monitor table. Similar information can be obtained from InnoDB INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables. See INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables for InnoDB.
>
> The innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog system variable.
>
> The innodb_stats_sample_pages system variable. Use innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages instead.
>
> The innodb_use_sys_malloc and the innodb_additional_mem_pool_size system variables.

but I suspect the functionality was removed long before that.  I have a note that says that innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is "unused since 4.1.0" -- That date backs about 15 years!!